# Model.aggregate is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongodb with mongoose, I am trying to aggerate inside my schema statistic construtor,

```
answerSchema.statics.calculateUserPoints = async function (userId) {
  let totalPoint = 0;
  let totalQnACount = 0;
  const user = await User.findById(userId);

  const articleStats = await Article.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        articleAuthor: userId,
      },
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: '$articleAuthor',
        articlePoints: {
          $sum: 15,
        },
        articleCount: {
          $sum: 1,
        },
      },
    },
  ]);

  const questionStats = await Question.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        questionAuthor: userId,
      },
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: '$questionAuthor',
        questionPoints: {
          $sum: 2,
        },
        questionCount: { $sum: 1 },
      },
    },
  ]);

  const answerStats = await this.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        answerAuthor: userId,
      },
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: '$answerAuthor',
        answerPoints: {
          $sum: 5,
        },
        answerCount: { $sum: 1 },
      },
    },
  ]);

  //Do Something With the Stats
};
```

But it is throwing an error,

```
TypeError: Article.aggregate is not a function
    at Function.answerSchema.statics.calculateUserPoints (C:\xx\xx\xx\clearConcept\models\answerModel.js:94:40)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

`Model.aggregate()` is working in other places but why not working here? My Article model import is correct i have checked, But why this is not working? and throwing this error?
If i use just `this.aggregate()` this one and delete another two aggregation then its working fine, But I also need that two aggregation also. How can I achieve this and fix this error?

Comment: Is userId is string?

Comment: @AsZik yes userId is String, i also tried that with mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId). Result is same.

Comment: did you tried with mongodb query ?

Comment: no, I just used that only, what about the query you talking? write them here pls,

Comment: @AsZik i can give you one more info my import lines are, 
const User = require('./userModel');
const Question = require('./questionModel');
const Article = require('./articleModel'); i have consoled console.log(this);
  console.log(Article);
  console.log(Question);
  console.log(User); this 4, the output is Model { Answer }
{}
{}
Model { User } why Question, and answer is empty. The files name are exact same and both are with user model, but why they are empty object? i didn't get that

Comment: you trying to assign the values to object ? answerSchema.statics.calculateUserPoints

Comment: I am not assigning those values but with that I am updating the user data.